# Passing arguments to at -f script

Tags: linux, bash, parameters, at-job

I'm trying to schedule a bash script using `at` command on Linux.

```
at 22:20 -f /path/to/script.sh
```

Issuing the command above works just fine. However, the script requires some parameters. Adding Params behind the script path returns an error message:

```
at 22:20 -f /path/to/script.sh /arg/one argtwo argthree
syntax error. Last token seen: /
```

Yes, the first parameter passed to the script is another (absolute) path. My guess is, that `at` doesn't treat my script as a script but rather as a file, as `at -help` implies.

How can I work around that and add params to the script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specify the command to run on stdin, e.g. via a here string:

```
at 22:20 <<< "/path/to/script.sh /arg/one argtwo argthree"
```

Your command does *not* try to run `/path/to/script.sh` at a certain time. Instead, it reads and copies all the commands from `/path/to/script.sh` and runs those later. Since you're not invoking the script itself, it doesn't make sense to talk about arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that it's taking just a filename, not a command. You should just run `at 22:20`, and then *as input to that command*, give the command you want run at 22:20 (i.e. `/path/to/script.sh /arg/one argtwo argthree`), and then Control-D on a separate line to mark the end of input. It should look a little like this (`$`  is my prompt):

```
$ at 22:20
/path/to/script.sh /arg/one argtwo argthree
job 11 at Thu May 27 22:20:00 2021
$
```

(Note that the "job 11 ..." is a confirmation message `at` printed.)

Answer (score 0):

You can give any command as input without the -f:

```
at 22:20 
/path/to/script.sh /arg/one argtwo argthree
^d
```